# If a problem is "not semi-decidable" and "not decidable" can we say it is "undecidable"?

Tags: undecidability, semi-decidability

I was under impression that when a Language (or problem) is not semi-decidable and not decidable then we can say it's undecidable and I think it makes sense also based on diagram.

[image]

However, in my assignment the TA struck out "undecidable" and wrote "not semi-decidable". Why is "undecidable" wrong if it's both not semi-decidable and not decidable?

Comment: You're right; the TA isn't.

Comment: @RickDecker thanks! If you like, write it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @RickDecker Huh? You don't even know what langauge the asker is talking about, so how on earth can you declare that it's not semi-decidable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undecidable isn't wrong: "undecidable" means exactly the same thing as "not decidable". However, your TA is saying that you can make the strictly stronger statement that the set is not even semi-decidable.  This implies that it's undecidable, but isn't implied by "it is undecidable".

Suppose you were, instead in a biology class. You wrote "This is not a lizard" and your TA crossed it out and wrote "This is not any kind of reptile." You're both right, but your TA's version has more information in it.

Comment: Thanks! I now understand it ... I missed the point that "not even SD" is stronger than "undecidable"